# CAKEPHP Retrieve post from a Db table skipping the first 2 results

Tags: cakephp

I would like to retrieve data from a specific table in the Db, but skip the first 2 results. Supposed I have the following:

1. An Articles controller with an Index action
2. I would like to use `$articles = $this->Articles->find('all' ...`

What code should I use to place those results into the `$articles` variable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the offset / limit of your query.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1018/find

`$articles = $this->Articles->find('all', array('offset' => 2));`